# How do I close a JDialog window using a JButton?

Tags: jframe, jbutton, jdialog

I've tried a bunch of different ways to close the window, but since you can't send additional parameters to to Action Listener method I can't dispose the frame due to a pointer exception for the frame.

This is my current code.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class errorRequiredFieldMissing extends JDialog{
JLabel error;
JButton exit;
public static JFrame frame;
public errorRequiredFieldMissing() {
    super(frame, "Error", true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    error = new JLabel ("Required field or fields missing, please fill in all fields to continue.");
    add(error);
    exit = new JButton ("OK");
    add(exit);
    System.out.println("chk1");
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            System.out.println("chk2");
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }); 
}
public static void method2(){
    System.out.print("success!");
    errorRequiredFieldMissing gui = new errorRequiredFieldMissing();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(400,100);
    gui.setLocation(300,25);
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        exitActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

and then

```
 private void exitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        this.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! But why does this work and not what I tried?

Comment: cause **frame** wasnt initialized (thats why you were getting a null pointer exception). actually you could keep your code exactly the same way you posted and just change the line 8 to `public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();`