# Do we need to use an intermediate method to "dispose()" in an ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, dispose, jdialog

I've found this answer on SO and was confused about it.

We have a question about someone who wants to know how to dispose of a JDialog within an ActionListener.

```
try this way:

exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        exitActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
and then

 private void exitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        this.dispose();
    }
```

This is the code that the person who answered has posted ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003892/how-do-i-close-a-jdialog-window-using-a-jbutton) the link to the question)

Here's what I'm doing in my own code :

```
buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
```

But I really am concerned about the answer above. Am I doing something wrong or doesn't it change anything if done like that? If it doesn't have an impact, would you know why the person answered by using an intermediate method?

Thank you

Comment: There's no difference, he is just calling a seperate method to dispose the dialog and nothing else.

Comment: The first variant is often how builder tools generate code. It makes it easier to insert larger code fragments, which should be preferably placed into the outer class. There is no semantic difference and you can omit this indirection if you are delegating to one existing method like `dispose()` anyway. It made a difference if `exitActionPerformed` was not `private`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I assume that your contains in **MyDialog** `class` which `extends`
>   `JDialog`

**Consider your following code.**

```
    exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

You have created an anonymous inner class of `java.awt.event.ActionListener`. If you use `this` keyword inside the the anonymous inner class it allows to access it self,  but not  `MyDialog` `class` as you expected. Therefore `this.dispose()` method is not available. But you can access it as **`MyDialog.this.dispose();`**

**Look at your second example**

```
    buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
```

Of course, `ActionListener` is also an anonymous inner class here. But it allows to access methods of it's containing class. So, it's possible to use `dispose()` method here.

Comment: I have not used the package name. I just used the class name `MyDialog`.

Answer (score 3):

Both have same effect.

That intermediate method might use to do some action before dispose. This type of action also be done with your version but using intermediate  method  might cause more readable.